# Why can't we change a particular value of a string in python

Tags: python, string

The string in python behaves similar to list. Then why can't we change value using assignment operator.

Example:

```
name = 'whatever'
```

why can't we do assignment like `name[0] = 'k'`

If we need to make a change like this, how can we do that?

Comment: because strings are immutable, you need to rebuild the string like `name = 'k' + name[1:]` but use a list if you want a mutable structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
s = "abcde"     # create string
l = list(s)     # convert to list
l[2] = "X"      # modify character
"".join(l)      # join to string again
```

Answer (score -1):

A string in Python is immutable. You can use something like .replace() or iterate through the string and create a new one.

For example:

```
name = 'whatever'
name.replace("w", "k")
```

Comment: please add example to your answer to show the intended usage

Comment: I added an example for .replace().
I understood the question as a more general one. I think the answer is the immutabilty of strings..?